# Unable to find add-ins in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I have OneNote installed on Windows 10 and I can’t for the life of me figure out where [this](https://github.com/elvirbrk/NoteHighlight2016) add-in I installed is. On the GitHub people recommend trying to run as an administrator, but upon right clicking to run as an administrator nothing shows up that lets me do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation from your link says:

> Default installation folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodingRoad\NoteHighlight2016\` or `C:\Program Files\CodingRoad\NoteHighlight2016\`

However, note that this relates only to the desktop version of OneNote and not to the
UWP version. You will not find the addon in the UWP version.

To learn more about the difference between the two versions and how to get the desktop
version, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1462711/8672).